# PHP: Call method with array?

Tags: php, arrays, methods, callback, call

Not quite sure how to word the title better.

What i need to do, is call a method with call_user_func. The method i'm calling accept several different variables (var1, var2, var3 etc), not an array. The problem is, when calling the function i need to pass the array i have as seperate variables to the method. Let me show you.

Here's my method:

```
class Test {

    public function testing_cronjob($p1, $p2, $p3, $p4, $p5) {
        echo 'p1 = ' . $p1 . '<br />';
        echo 'p1 = ' . $p2 . '<br />';
        echo 'p1 = ' . $p3 . '<br />';
        echo 'p1 = ' . $p4 . '<br />';
        echo 'p1 = ' . $p5 . '<br />';
    }
}
```

And here's how i currently (try) to call it:

```
$obj = new Test();
call_user_func(array($obj, 'testing_cronjob'), $params);
```

The method runs, but it only gets one variable, which is not what i want.

$params look like this:

```
$params = array(
    0 => 'first one',
    1 => 'second one',
    2 => 'third param!',
    3 => 'oh and im fourth!!',
    4 => 'im last, fml! :('
)
```

The way i got myself into this situation, is because i'm creating a cronjob model. It accepts params along with class and method name. It's all stored in a database, and when it runs, i need to be able to send the $params to the method as intended.

I can't rewrite how methods accept variables, because that would be way too much work. I'm going to be calling several (10+) methods from the cronjob, all of which are pretty well used in the application. I'm also not sure how i would re-write it, but if you have any suggestions about that, let me know.

Also, i'm using codeigniter if that matters. If i forgot to mention anything or you want more code, just drop a comment.

Is this possible? Are there any workarounds? Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)  instead:

```
$obj = new Test();
call_user_func_array(array($obj, 'testing_cronjob'), $params);
```

Comment: Oh you have got to be F@*&/#G kidding me! Here i sat, spending hours trying to solve this, only to write a question here and get told i only need to append 6 tiny little words to the end of the function name, and voila, it works! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Minor nitpick: always read the whole manual page for the PHP functions you're having trouble with. The page on `call_user_func` includes a link to `call_user_func_array` on the bottom ("see also:")